# Using VMware, why aren't my network adapters visible to the guest Linux OS

Tags: linux, vmware, network-adapter, vmware-player

I have a Centos 6 - 64 bit guest OS running in VMware Workstation Player 14 on a Windows 7 Machine.  The problem I'm having is I can't see any of the network adapters I've set up. I've tried NAT, bridged, host-only, and now all three at once.  When I run ***ifconfig*** I only see the lo Loopback interface.

I've added a screen shot of the ***ifconfig*** output, the VMware network adapter settings, and ipconfig output to show that the network adapters are up on the host machine.  Hope that helps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A VMware Guest machine will use the Network Adapter of the Host machine connection and will normally show up in the guest as a wired adapter.  Whether NAT or Bridged, ifconfig should show the IP for the Host Subnet (Bridged) or the IP address of the NAT setup. I use VMware Network Editor to find this subnet.

Comment: Enter `ip link show` in a root terminal within the VM and add its output to the question.  Centos 6 is also very old so if you haven't installed any updates or are not using an updated version it may not have the right paravirtualized drivers to recognize the VMWare virtual NICs.

Comment: @LawrenceC Ok, just added the output of ***ip link show*** .  Looks like it sees the adapters, so why can't I use them?

Comment: They say DOWN.  Do a 'ip link set ethX up' for each interface.

Comment: @LawrenceC, Worked perfect.  I'm up and running now.  Thanks.

Comment: So you'll probably be in the same situation when you restart the VM.  You need to figure out how to run those `set up` commands on boot or configure the interfaces to be up at boot.  I know how to do that for Debian but not Centos.